# Can we use SOSL to search content libraries

Tags: sosl, content

We are in the process of building a custom visual force page whose requirement is to search content libraries and files related to it based on a text entered on a search box. The requirement is to search 100,000 characters inside a file which is associated to a content library based on search text entered in a text box. Can we use SOSL queries to search files inside a content library? Can you guys share custom code or blogs related to custom search within a content library?
Thanks
Buyan

Answer (score 2):

Here is little experiment that I did for this ,

Uploaded a word document(14 pages long) in the Content Object .

[image]

The next thing I did was to pick a very random word thats there in the document .

Ran the below SOSL to see if the query searches inside the file

```java
FIND {ITW*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ContentVersion(Title)
```

Observe the results below

[image]

Looked into [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_search.htm) to find limitations and here is what I gathered

> The search engine looks for matches to the search term across a maximum of 2,000 records (this limit starts with API version 28.0).
>
> The search term cannot be greater than 10000 characters
>
> Searching document content supports multiple file types and has file size limits. The contents of documents that exceed the maximum sizes are not searched; however, the document fields are still searched. **Only the first 1,000,000 characters of text are searched.** Text beyond this limit is not included in the search.